# Make content attribute text selectable

Tags: css

I have a cool tooltip to work with using some data attributes as seen here :
http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/css-tooltips/

But the problem is the text inside the tooltip is not selectable, even after I add property:

```
cursor: text;
```

Any idea how to make that tooltip selectable?

Thanks

UPDATE:
This doesn't seem to help either:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: all;
-webkit-user-select: all;
-khtml-user-select: all;
-moz-user-select: all;
-ms-user-select: all;
user-select: all;
```

Values: none | text | toggle | element | elements | all | inherit

Ref:

[How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the kind of tooltip to do this.

Try something with jQuery like this one
(random google search: http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html)

Or look at this website with a compilation of tooltip scripts
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Comment: Thanks alot for alternatives. This is the closest I can get with data attributes: http://www.red-team-design.com/easy-css3-jquery-tooltips

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make it selectable. The hint must exists only on :hover of the element. I had a hard time to move the mouse over the hint itself.

btw i suggest to remove the animation from the css (and make opacity: 1) it's much nicer and responsive.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I do agree and remove those animation